# delete multiple entry in mysql but keep one php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i having a problem in cleaning data from the entry in database.

so i have a table "users" with the field (id, name, email, phone)

the problem i have is to delete the duplication based on the phone number. i have around 30k of data entry and i need to make sure that each of the data  in the table must consist a record with different "phone number" bcoz right now what i have is 
(example:
3 same people with the same phone number

```
name:   Phone No:
john     1234
john     1234
john     1234
```

i only need to keep one record with one phone number.

is there any php script than can work on this case faster.hope you guys can help me.

Comment: so run a SELECT on all records for the same phone number. If found, DELETE it for the different id; what's so hard about that?

Comment: in any case, you should have set a UNIQUE constraint from the beginning.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key or unique id?

Comment: btw; you're going to wait an awful long time for the circus to come to town and hoping the magician's still part of the company (payroll) to get a solution here.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21314/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql-table-that-does-not-contain-primary-key

Comment: if you have an unique field so you can diference between  each name is easy Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql) otherwise you need create a temporal table as the previous link.

Comment: Check my answer dude

Answer (score 0):

You can delete with a join. In this example you keep the lowest `users.id`.

```
DELETE t1 FROM users AS t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT MIN(id) AS min_id FROM users GROUP BY phone) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.min_id WHERE t2.min_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE users
ADD UNIQUE INDEX p (phone);
```

This will drop all the duplicate rows and doesn't allow future INSERT with the same phone value.